# Bug in Full calendar in getDate comment

Tags: jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

i am using arshaw fullcalendar("FullCalendar v1.6.4") in that i use  date-picker for jump date in week view
this is my code..

```
$('.calendar2').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate',new Date($scope.jump));
```

then i click next button calender move to next week in that button click i am getDate 
ie)

```
`$(document).on("click", ".fc-button-next", function(){`
 var d = $('.calendar2').fullCalendar('getDate');
console.log(d);
})
```

it wont give Monday date it give

if i select Tuesday in jump date-picker it gives Tuesdays date for that (var d) not monday date of the week

is there any solution tell me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For month view, it will always be sometime between the first and last day of the month. For week views, it will always be sometime between the first and last day of the week.

**[See This](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/getDate/)**

Comment: thanks for reply i got it any way i take the day of the week and minus to the day which return and i got the Monday date of the week

Comment: Thanks for sharing that.Will certainly help someone in future who refers this.